# Disable filesystem read cache

Tags: filesystem, cache

How can I disable the Linux file system read cache for Ubuntu 12.04?

I don't want to only free the actual cache.

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

but disable the read cache completely.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might find what you're looking for in this superuser answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/242928/disable-linux-read-and-write-file-cache-on-partition

The code linked from that answer is no longer available at code.google.com though, but it has been cloned to github:  https://github.com/svn2github/pagecache-management

The instructions in that answer should still work though.  Hope this helps!